# Server to Client Notification / Web service(jax-ws) to client communication

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am going to write a smart client application. This application will be swing based desktop client that will communicate with web service. I want to be a message has been sent to client from web service when any change occurs at server side file system. I wanted to use web services but I am not sure how I would implement a two-way communication between the server and client. Is it possible? If so how? If not what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to program your client to be able to ping a request after a predefined frequency to check if there is a changes occurred on the server side. The client expect the changes occurred on the server or null if no change.

Comment: Thanks the same idea was in my mind,but i need immediate action on client side if some thing changes on server side, when i will ping my server time by time, it will degrade performance , because i have to write a separate thread to ping the server. and the that thread will be in running condition all the times. i need some other solution like if some change occurs on server side, it will send an immediate action to client side.\

Comment: IMO, There is no way to tell your server that these clients are waiting for the responses. So you have to stick to request/response procedure.